# AngularJs ng-disabled is not working in IE 9 any solution?

Tags: angularjs, cross-browser

I have issue with ng-disabled AngularJs directive its working good in chrome but its not working in IE 9 , Any solution to make it work will be appreciated.

main.html

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list k-data-text-field="'text'"
    k-option-label="'Select'" k-data-value-field="'id'"
    k-data-source="assessmentOptions" name="riskAssesLevelLookupCode"
    required id="riskAssesLevelLookupCode"
    maxlength="256"
    ng-attr-disabled="{{disableAssessmentType? 'disabled': ''}}"
    ng-model="riskAssessmentDTO.riskAssesLevelLookupCode"
></select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm currently having the same issue with `ng-disabled`. Unfortunately, the only workaround that I could think of was to handle the logic of the `ng-disabled` in the controller. So in your case:

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list k-data-text-field="'text'"
    k-option-label="'Select'" k-data-value-field="'id'"
    k-data-source="assessmentOptions" name="riskAssesLevelLookupCode"
    Required id="riskAssesLevelLookupCode"
    maxlength="256"
    ng-attr-disabled="checkForDisabled()"
    ng-model="riskAssessmentDTO.riskAssesLevelLookupCode">
</select>
```

And in the controller:

```
checkForDisabled() {
    if(disableAssessmentType) {
       return "disabled";
    } else {
       return "";
    }
}
```

Then again, this won't garanty the right behavior on IE9. In my case I was trying to avoid the functionality of an `ng-click` event. So I set a flag to `false` when the disabled was set and according to that flag I called the function. Something like this:

```
<button ng-click="callMethod()" ng-disabled="checkDisabled()">
  Click me if Im enabled
</button>
```

Controller:

```
checkDisabled() {
   // Let's say it's disabled
   $scope.isDisabled = false; // set a global flag
   return false;
}

callMethod() {
   if($scope.isDisabled) {
        //disabled, do nothing maybe handle an error?
   } else {
        //functionality when it's enabled
   }
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue - moving logic from expression to controller solved the problem. It is mindblowing how IE interprets stuff